# Is there a culture-safe way to get ToShortDateString() and ToShortTimeString() with leading zeros?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I know that I could use a format string, but I don't want to lose the culture specific representation of the date/time format. E.g.

`5/4/2011 | 2:06 PM | ...` should be `05/04/2011 | 02:06 PM | ...`

But when I change it to a different culture, I want it to be

`04.05.2011 | 14:06 | ...`

without changing the format string. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see only a single solution -  you should obtain the current culture display format, patch it so that it meets your requirement and finally format your DateTime value using the patched format string.  Here is some sample code:

```
string pattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string[] format = pattern.Split(new string[] { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string newPattern = string.Empty;
        for(int i = 0; i < format.Length; i++) {
            newPattern = newPattern + format[i];
            if(format[i].Length == 1)
                newPattern += format[i];
            if(i != format.Length - 1)
                newPattern += CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
        }
```

As promised, here is the improved version:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extensions for the <see cref="DateTime"/> class.
/// </summary>
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the same functionality as the ToShortDateString() method, but
    /// with leading zeros.
    /// <example>
    /// ToShortDateString: 5/4/2011 |
    /// ToShortDateStringZero: 05/04/2011
    /// </example>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Source date.</param>
    /// <returns>Culture safe short date string with leading zeros.</returns>
    public static string ToShortDateStringZero(this DateTime source)
    {
        return ToShortStringZero(source,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the same functionality as the ToShortTimeString() method, but
    /// with leading zeros.
    /// <example>
    /// ToShortTimeString: 2:06 PM |
    /// ToShortTimeStringZero: 02:06 PM
    /// </example>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Source date.</param>
    /// <returns>Culture safe short time string with leading zeros.</returns>
    public static string ToShortTimeStringZero(this DateTime source)
    {
        return ToShortStringZero(source,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator);
    }

    private static string ToShortStringZero(this DateTime source, 
        string pattern,
        string seperator)
    {
        var format = pattern.Split(new[] {seperator}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        var newPattern = string.Empty;

        for (var i = 0; i < format.Length; i++)
        {
            newPattern = newPattern + format[i];
            if (format[i].Length == 1)
                newPattern += format[i];
            if (i != format.Length - 1)
                newPattern += seperator;
        }

        return source.ToString(newPattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked really well, I'm going to improve it a little bit.

Comment: Finished it. Works really well, but I only tested it with en-US and de-AT

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.currentinfo.aspx) [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx) and [`ShortTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern.aspx) to do the translation:

```
// Change the culture to something different
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-AT");
DateTime test_datetime = new DateTime(2008, 10, 2, 3, 22, 12);
string s_date = test_datetime.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);

// For specifically the short date and time
string s_date1 = 
   test_datetime.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern);
string s_time1 = 
   test_datetime.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern);

// Results
// s_date1 == 02.10.2008
// s_time1 == 03:22
```

Answer (score 9):

Really complicated answers here. In reality it's as simple as

```
datetime.ToString("d", culture) // Short date
datetime.ToString("t", culture) // Short time
```

For a full list of all formats with example outputs see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0.

Answer (score 3):

You could also override the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture class. At the beginning of your program you call this method:

```
    private void FixCurrentDateFormat()
    {
        var cc = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        var df = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        df.FullDateTimePattern = PatchPattern(df.FullDateTimePattern);
        df.LongDatePattern = PatchPattern(df.LongDatePattern);
        df.ShortDatePattern = PatchPattern(df.ShortDatePattern);
        //change any other patterns that you could use

        //replace the current culture with the patched culture
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cc;
    }

    private string PatchPattern(string pattern)
    {
        //modify the pattern to your liking here
        //in this example, I'm replacing "d" with "dd" and "M" with "MM"
        var newPattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\bd\b", "dd");
        newPattern = Regex.Replace(newPattern, @"\bM\b", "MM");
        return newPattern;
    }
```

With this, anywhere you display a date as a string in your program it will have the new format.

Comment: What is the \b backspace character in the match for?

Comment: Ah forget about it, I figured it out (word boundary). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_escapes

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method to do that kind of transformations :

```
/// <summary>
/// Transform DateTime into short specified format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strDateTime">string : input DateTime</param>
/// <param name="cultureInfo"></param>
/// <param name="strFormat">string - optional : ouput format - default "d"</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ConvertDateTimeToShortDate(string strDateTime, CultureInfo cultureInfo, string strFormat="d")
{
  var dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
  return DateTime.TryParse(strDateTime, out dateTime) ? dateTime.ToString(strFormat, cultureInfo) : strDateTime;
}
```

To call it, for time format  :

```
DateTimeTools.ConvertDateTimeToShortDate(DateTime.Today.ToString(),
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"t");
```

Hope it can help u