# Format a date using the current thread culture Vs double digits for month and day?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I want to display some rows of data on a web page where one column is a DateTime.
I want the date format to be displayed based on the current thread culture.

Right now, I'm doing this (dt is a DateTime):

```
string s = dt.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

It's working well, however, on some culture, months and days are represented as only one digit (hours too), for example:

```
8/8/2011 8:57:59 AM
```

I would like the date to be displayed like this:

```
08/08/2011 08:57:59 AM
```

It would be easier to read (and prettier) when there's a list of rows.
I saw that there's a `String.format` method I could use, but that makes the current culture irrelevant.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You should respect the user's localization settings.

Comment: I want to show it based on the current culture, like 02/24/2011 Vs 2011/02/24 for example... but not have 2/24/2011 cause it's ugly and hard to read in a list

Comment: make a list of cultures you would like to offend and use a default culture if one of those cultures is the current one. So make a method GetCurrentCulture

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to offend anybody... I just thought that displaying a list of dates in a view without the same length is difficult to read. Personally, as a user, I would rather see some double digits, but that might just be me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654695/is-there-a-culture-safe-way-to-get-toshortdatestring-and-toshorttimestring-wi/6654743#6654743) might be useful.

> I see only a single solution - you should obtain the current culture display format, patch it so that it meets your requirement and finally format your DateTime value using the patched format string.

Answer (score 2):

Make a [custom culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx).

Base it on the current thread culture.

Modify the settings you want to override.

Then either set it back into the thread as the culture or use it temporarily during the format operation.

We currently do this to format all dates in an internationally unambiguous form ddMMMyyyy where MMM is only English three-letter abbreviations, yet obey local numeric formatting rules ./, etc.

The relevant properties to override would [be here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show it based on the current culture, then what is the problem? If you want a specific format, you have to specify that.

```
string text = myDateTime.ToString("{0:[your format]}");
```

Comment: I want to show it based on the current culture, like 02/24/2011 Vs 2011/02/24 for example... but not have 2/24/2011 cause it's ugly and hard to read in a list

Answer (score 0):

I believe this defaults to the server format - but what if you try specifying "u" as the format code which will put the year first then I think two digits.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that also. It sure does display two digits, but the proper date format for the culture is not respected... for example, in US, it should be MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Then the other option to try is set the default on the server's control panel so for instance if its in the US, it gives two digits everything. If you can do that (not 100% sure) then try your code again and see if it properly formats)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM PM ", yourDatetime)
```

The date separator / (slash) and time sepatator : (colon) will be rewritten to characters defined in the current DateTimeForma­tInfo.DateSepa­rator and DateTimeForma­tInfo.TimeSepa­rator.

EDIT: Forgot to add object param needed to the string.format

Comment: Yeah, I first did this, but it respect only the "/" and ":" for the culture, not the proper date format... for example, in US, it's should be MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @canam just a comment... be careful if u're doing it on a column. Make sure that columns show which culture it is. imagine something like "12/01/2011" (dd/mm) and in the next line there is a date "12/01/2011" (mm/dd/YYY)

Comment: Good point... but since we have a user preference to specify desired culture, users should know what to expect

Comment: If there is no multi-culture in the same column (all dates are parsed in the current logged user culture) you can use `string.format("{0:g}", yourDatetime);` but there is the left zeroes issue  source: [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Globalization;
private static CultureInfo defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

public static CultureInfo GetCurrentCulture()
{
    List<CultureInfo> badCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
    badCultures.Add(new CultureInfo("en-US"));

    if (badCultures.Contains(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture))
        return defaultCulture;
    return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
```