# Compare date of different date formats with help of "CompareValidator"

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datetime

I have added following code in aspx page

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CmpStartdateVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start date should be greater than Current date"
                Font-Size="Large" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" EnableTheming="True"
                Operator="GreaterThan" ValidationGroup="Validation" Type="Date">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

and added following line in code behind

```
CmpStartdateVal.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

It works fine if my PC's date format is MM/dd/yyyy , but it gives error when i change my PC's date format to **dd-MMM-yyyy** or **yy-mm-dd**.
Please help in finding solution which will work for all date formats.

Comment: You could use: `DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` to force this format.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but i want generalized code which will work for any date format. i tried this code with DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); but of no use

Comment: You can change the Thread Culture.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654695/is-there-a-culture-safe-way-to-get-toshortdatestring-and-toshorttimestring-w for a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
CmpStartdateVal.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

you could use

```
CmpStartdateVal.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to force a format that the `CompareValidator` understands.

or you could change the culture for this page via page-directive:

```
<%@ Page .... Culture="en-US" UICulture="en-US" %>
```

Another option for an arbitrary date format is to change the `ShortDatePatern` of the curent culture which is used by the `CompareValidator`. You could do this in `Page_Init`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var culture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

Comment: it gives error "The value '01/23/2014' of the ValueToCompare property of 'CmpStartdateVal' cannot be converted to type 'Date'."
edit : my PC's format is dd-MMM-yy

Comment: @user3201354: i have edited my answer to provide another approach.